# Validation for a list with multiple parents and multiple children (graph)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, validation, graph-databases

I have the following list:

[image]

Is a many-to-many recursive association where a category (Computers, Mac, PCs etc.) can have many other categories. Also a category (like optical drives) can belong to PCs and Mac. But the "optical drives" shouldn't allow to have a category as the "PCs" category because it will have an endless loop.

I am wondering how can I create the above validation in Rails and be optimized? Should I check all the parent categories? But this would result in many sql queries if there are many nested categories (for example 200 depth of children categories).

Another thought was to create a depth column in database and make a validation where a parent category shouldn't allow to have as a child, a category with a depth smaller than it's own depth. But that wouldn't allow the scenario of having a category with no common parents, into another depth. For example in the above list-example, optical drives could have as a category the Mac even if it is in an above depth-level. But it couldn't have the PCs because of the endless loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a node can have more than one parent, this is a graph, not a tree. While there are [patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202) to handle graphs in relational databases, I've found them cumbersome. This is where graph databases shine.

For sake of illustration, I'll show you a potential solution to your problem in Gremlin, a graph traversal language that runs in Neo4j through a plugin and is available through the [Neo4j REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/gremlin-plugin.html).

The latest version of Gremlin included in Neo4j is Gremlin 1.5. You can download this version from [Github](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/downloads) to try out this code:

```
g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/so')

// add all vertices
categories = ['Computers', 'Mac', 'PCs', 'Hard Disks', 'Memory', 'Graphic Cards',
'Optical Drives', 'DVD-Reader', 'DVD-RW', 'Blue Ray', 'Blue Ray / DVD Combo']

categories.each { x -> g.addVertex(['name':x]) }

// show all of the vertices we just created with their properties
g.V.map
==>{name=Computers}
==>{name=Mac}
==>{name=PCs}
==>{name=Hard Disks}
==>{name=Memory}
==>{name=Graphic Cards}
==>{name=Optical Drives}
==>{name=DVD-Reader}
==>{name=DVD-RW}
==>{name=Blue Ray}
==>{name=Blue Ray / DVD Combo}

// for ease of this example, create a lookup table of these vertices
// in a production system, you would look up vertices in a Lucene index
i = [:]
g.V.transform {i[it.name] = it}

// create edges representing one category 'in' another
g.addEdge(i['Mac'], i['Computers'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['PCs'], i['Computers'], 'in')

// PCs subgraph
g.addEdge(i['Hard Disks'], i['PCs'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['Memory'], i['PCs'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['Graphic Cards'], i['PCs'], 'in')

// optical drives subgraph
g.addEdge(i['Optical Drives'], i['PCs'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['DVD-Reader'], i['Optical Drives'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['DVD-RW'], i['Optical Drives'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['Blue Ray'], i['Optical Drives'], 'in')
g.addEdge(i['Blue Ray / DVD Combo'], i['Optical Drives'], 'in')

// adding the optical drive subgraph to Mac is a one-liner
g.addEdge(i['Optical Drives'], i['Mac'], 'in')

// show the names of all vertices in the paths from Computers to child nodes three-levels down
i['Computers'].in.in.in.paths {it.name}
==>[Computers, PCs, Optical Drives, Blue Ray / DVD Combo]
==>[Computers, PCs, Optical Drives, Blue Ray]
==>[Computers, PCs, Optical Drives, DVD-RW]
==>[Computers, PCs, Optical Drives, DVD-Reader]
==>[Computers, Mac, Optical Drives, Blue Ray / DVD Combo]
==>[Computers, Mac, Optical Drives, Blue Ray]
==>[Computers, Mac, Optical Drives, DVD-RW]
==>[Computers, Mac, Optical Drives, DVD-Reader]

g.shutdown()
```

Gremlin can take some time to get used to, as it's a functional programming approach, but it's very powerful once you get the hang of it.

> > But the 'optical drives' shouldn't allow to have a category as the 'PCs' category because it will have an endless loop.

This sort of validation can be handled by pathfinding. If there exists a path from the current vertex to the child vertex, then don't allow the edge to be created. Neo4j includes a [Pathfinder API](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphalgo/PathFinder.html) to facilitate these sorts of searches.

Since you're in Rails, you might find Neo4j paired up with a RESTful wrapper like [neography](http://rubygems.org/gems/neography) provides the integration between Rails and Neo4j that you'll need. Neo4j also offers the ability to create [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) if you want to create custom RESTful endpoints.